# How to set initial view properties?

Tags: itext

Here I want to set the already exist PDF document properties under **Initial View** tab in acrobat.

**Document Options:**

- Show = Bookmarks Panel and Page
- Page Layout = Continuous
- Magnification = Fit Width
- Open to Page number = 1

**Window Options:**

- Show = Document Title

As show in below screen shot:

**I am tried following code:**

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dPDFFile, FileMode.Create));
stamper.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.DISPLAYDOCTITLE, new PdfBoolean(true));
```

the above code is used to set the document title show.

But following code are **not working**

For Page Layout:

```
stamper.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PAGELAYOUT, new PdfName("OneColumn"));
```

For Bookmarks Panel and Page:

```
stamper.AddViewerPreference(PdfName. PageMode, new PdfName("UseOutlines"));
```

So please give guide me what is the correct way to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm adding an extra answer in answer to the extra question in the comments of the previous answer:

When you have a `PdfWriter` instance named `writer`, you can set the Viewer preferences like this:

```
writer.ViewerPreferences = viewerpreference;
```

In this case, the `viewerpreference` is a value that can have one of the following values:

- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage`
- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutOneColumn`
- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutTwoColumnLeft`
- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutTwoColumnRight`
- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutTwoPageLeft`
- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutTwoPageRight`

See the [PageLayoutExample](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=228) for more info.

You can also change the page mode as is shown in the [ViewerPreferencesExample](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=229). In which case the different values are "OR"-ed:

- `PdfWriter.PageModeFullScreen`
- `PdfWriter.PageModeUseThumbs`
- `PdfWriter.PageLayoutTwoColumnRight | PdfWriter.PageModeUseThumbs`
- `PdfWriter.PageModeFullScreen | PdfWriter.NonFullScreenPageModeUseOutlines`
- `PdfWriter.FitWindow | PdfWriter.HideToolbar`
- `PdfWriter.HideWindowUI`

Currently, you've only used the PrintPreferences example from the official documentation:

```
writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PRINTSCALING, PdfName.NONE);
writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.NUMCOPIES, new PdfNumber(3));
writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);
```

But in some cases, it's just easier to use:

```
writer.ViewerPreferences = viewerpreference;
```

Note that the official documentation is the book ["iText in Action - Second Edition."](http://itextpdf.com/book/) The examples are written in Java, but you can find the C# version [here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178). There is a new book in the works called "The ABC of PDF", but so far only 4 chapters were written. You'll find more info here: http://itextpdf.com/learn

The part about the different options to create a `PdfDestination` is already present in "The ABC of PDF".

As for setting the language, this is done like this:

```
stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.LANG, new PdfString("EN"));
```

The result is shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

As you can see, there is now a `Lang` entry with value `EN` added to the catalog.

Comment: I have one more question how to set Reading option _Language = English_ PS Script for set _Language = English_ is `[ {Catalog} <</Lang(EN)>> /PUT pdfmark`

Comment: i am tried `stamper.Writer.SetLanguage("EN");` but it's not working

Comment: This is a case where you need `stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.LANG, new PdfString("EN"));`

Comment: `stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName key,PdfObject value);` is not working other options also like **PAGEMODE**, **PAGELAYOUT** so on.

Comment: I've tried it myself and it works for me. See the attached screen shot. Maybe you're using an old iTextSharp version where this functionality isn't supported yet...

Comment: Yes Bruno not added but `/PageLayout:/OneColumn`, `/PageMode:/UseOutlines` are available under root catalog

Comment: i am using itextsharp.dll version 5.4.3.0, what about your version?

Comment: I'm using iText 5.5.1: see http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddLanguage (you can download the PDF and check for the `Lang` entry using RUPS).

Comment: Ya i got it Bruno, now it's working in itextSharp 5.5.1.0, you really great thanks for your patient answer and support.

Comment: It was a good question (hence the up-vote). Usually people always post the same questions over and over again. Yours was a new one ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your contribution I need more support from you please be on touch, once again thanks for your support

Answer (score 8):

The two items *Show = Bookmarks Panel and Page* and *Page Layout = Continuous* are controlled one layer up from the `ViewerPreferences` in the document's `/Catalog`. You can get to this via:

```
stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog
```

In your case you're looking for:

```
// Acrobat's Single Page
stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.PAGELAYOUT, PdfName.ONECOLUMN);
// Show bookmarks
stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.PAGEMODE, PdfName.USEOUTLINES);
```

The items *Magnification = Fit Width* and *Open to Page number = 1* are also part of the `/Catalog` but in a special key called `/OpenAction`. You can set this using:

```
stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction();
```

In your case you're looking for:

```
//Create a destination that fit's width (fit horizontal)
var D = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH);

//Create an open action that points to a specific page using this destination
var OA = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, D, stamper.Writer);

//Set the open action on the writer
stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction(OA);
```

Comment: In your code _Open to Page number_ only working other then all are not working and also `PdfDestination.FITH` setting the _Magnification = Fit Page_ not _Fit Width_

Comment: This is my PS Script Code used to set those setting in PDF

`[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /View [/FitH -32768]/Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark`

`[ {Catalog} <</ViewerPreferences<</DisplayDocTitle true>>/PageLayout/OneColumn>> /PUT pdfmark`

but now i want to do this by iTextSharp with c# in already existing PDF

Comment: That's just a matter of creating a `PdfDestination` object using other parameters. For instance `new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH, -32768)` as described in the documentation.

Comment: In which documentation i can get this and all please provid link

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, Great its working, what about this `[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /DOCVIEW pdfmark` and `[ {Catalog} <</ViewerPreferences /Lang(EN) /PageLayout/OneColumn>> /PUT pdfmark` how i can set those and all?

Comment: Try these examples: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter13/PageLayoutExample.cs and http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter13/ViewerPreferencesExample.cs

Comment: @Chris Haas Sorry Chris your code also working now first i was tried in iTextSharp 5.4.3.0 but now working in iTextSharp 5.5.1.0. thanks for your answer, great

Comment: Thanks this bit showed bookmark for me :) stamper.Writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(PdfName.PAGEMODE, PdfName.USEOUTLINES);