# How to Get/Set Fast Web View in PDF file using iTextSharp with C#

Tags: itext

Here I am using iTextSharp to open PDF document and changing some properties such as page layout as guidance from this link [How to set initial view properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370273/set-initial-view-pdf-document-properties-using-itextsharp-with-c-sharp)

Problem:
Input PDF Fast Web View : True but out put PDF Fast Web View : False, but I want Fast Web View must True when input PDF Fast Web View is True.

So

1. I want to Get/read exist Fast Web View value
2. In I want to Set/Update new(my) Fast Web View value

In PDF document.

Input PDF Properties:
[image]

output PDF Properties:
[image]

Comment: I have same problem in java. i solved it using tool

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is linearization. See [this post directly from iText](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/142) which basically says iText has no native support for this and they currently don't have any future plans for it. From that page:

> Linearization doesn't make any sense for dynamically created files or for files that need to be served to a mobile device. It would be "Slow Web View".
>
> ...
>
> Up until now, we've had several users asking for linearized PDFs, but
> once they fully understood that linearization would slow down the
> download process rather than make it faster, they decided against it.
> That's why we never put Linearization on our roadmap. Of course: if
> somebody wants to sponsor the development: you're always welcome to do
> so.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I see that the OP also marked "Tagged PDF". If you want to know how to make a "Tagged PDF", please take a look at these slides: http://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/itext-summit14pdfarchivingaccessibility

Comment: oh k k, can i go with Acrobat for this process?

Comment: @ThirusangurajaVenkatesan, is your comment about linearization or tagged PDF, two unrelated things.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Sorry for confusion, I am updated my question, I am looking for only Fast Web View (linearization)

Comment: @Thirusanguraja Venkatesan, Have you got solution for the Fast Web View. If so please share it the answer. Also have you tried using Itext or some other stuff.