# pdf generation using itextsharp everything is fine but file is not getting generated

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, html-to-pdf

I have a query related to PDF generation from HTML code. I have a table written in HTML code and I want to parse it in a PDF writer using iTextSharp.dll, I have been using the same code with different html content in another section of my website and it is working absolutely fine.

Here is my code below please do comment.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='3'>");
//sb.Append("<tr><td colspan=4><img src='logo.png' width='250px' height = '70px'/></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td></td><td colspan=2 align=center>JK Cement Works, Jharli</td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Duplicate Tickets</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Print DateTime:</td><td>");
sb.Append(printDT.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Transaction Number</td><td>");
sb.Append(tNum.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Truck Number</td><td>");
sb.Append(TruckNum.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Product Code</td><td>");
sb.Append(pCode.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td>Product Name</td><td>");
sb.Append(pName.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Supplier Code</td><td>");
sb.Append(sCode.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td>Supplier Name</td><td>");
sb.Append(sName.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Transporter Code</td><td>");
sb.Append(tCode.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td>Transporter Name</td><td>");
sb.Append(tName.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Challan Number</td><td>");
sb.Append(challanNum.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td>Challan DateTime</td><td>");
sb.Append(challanDT.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td colspan=2>Delivery Note Number</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Shift</td><td>");
sb.Append(shift.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>IN DateTime</td><td>");
sb.Append(InDT.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td>Gross Weight</td><td>");
sb.Append(gWeight.Text.ToString());
sb.Append(" Tons</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td>Out DateTime</td><td>");
sb.Append(OutDT.Text.ToString());
sb.Append("</td><td>Tare Weight</td><td>");
sb.Append(tWeight.Text.ToString());
sb.Append(" Tons</td></tr>");
sb.Append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td>Net Weight</td><td>");
sb.Append(nWeight.Text.ToString());
sb.Append(" Tons</td></tr></table>");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);                        
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();                        
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=InvoiceSJ.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(pdfDoc);                        
Response.End();
```

Comment: Which version of iText? `HTMLWorker` is deprecated, please use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: I would just like to know if anything wrong i am doing here. Please let me know. As I already told before that in other part of my site this code is working fine, with proper result.

Answer (score 1):

You first write the PDF to the `Response.OutputStream`

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);                        
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

only to immediately thereafter clear the `Response` (and so throw the PDF away)

```
Response.Clear();
```

and eventually output `pdfDoc`

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

which does not make sense because the iTextSharp `Document` class does not hold the PDF document, it merely is a front end class via which you provide content for the PDF. This content is forwarded to a `PdfWriter` which as soon as possible writes the content in PDF form to its output stream.

Please try, therefore, something along these lines:

```
[... create StringReader sr ...]

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=InvoiceSJ.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);                        
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();

Response.End();
```

---

Depending on the very browser and version, a `Content-Length` header might be required. If the above does not work for you yet, therefore, please try writing the PDF to a `MemoryStream` and get the PDF as a `byte[]`, then initialize the `Response`, set a `Content-Length` header with the length of the array and then write that array.

---

That been said, the `HTMLWorker` indeed has been deprecated a long time ago; for serious development you should use the `XMLWorker` instead, just like Amedee commented.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But my problem is still not resolved, as you might have expected. So would like to know about the alternative way that you have mentioned: using array.

Comment: @SwapnilJain The code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30623068/1729265) uses an intermediate `byte[]`.